# Is every open subset of $\mathbb R^n$ unbounded?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> Is every open subset of $\mathbb R^n$ unbounded?

It seems that definition of an open subset of $\mathbb R^n$ makes it impossible to have a boundary because for every point of the boundary will contain a neighbourhood not contained in the subset itself.

Comment: No, any open interval of the form $(a, b)$ for finite $a, b$ is open and bounded. The same holds true for open balls of finite radius in other dimensions.

Comment: @user1620696 so Let's assume R^2 is considered so a E=(2,5) which is basically a single point in the plane cannot be considered as an open subset ??

Comment: No, the set $\{(a,b) \in \mathbb{R}^2\}\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ consisting of a single point is not open. The same holds true if you have a finite collection of points. Recall the definition of open set and ask yourself: what happens if you try to build an open ball with center on the single point with some arbitrary radius?

Comment: @Shuri2060 I know a point cannot be open subset because here the norm will be zero

Comment: I see the confusion - the notation '$(a,b)$' can be ambiguous. In the first comment, it refers to an open interval in $\Bbb R$ and not an ordered pair in $\Bbb R^2$. ie. $]a,b[$, or $\{x\in\Bbb R\mid a<x<b\}$ and not $(a,b)\in\Bbb R^2$

Comment: An open set is allowed to have a boundary, however the boundary is disjoint from the open set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that boundary is not about boundness of a set.

You already know the definition of boundary.

For instance if you take the interval $(0,1)$ then this inteval has a boundary which is the set $\{0,1\}$ and also the set $(0,1)$ is bounded.

Also note that $boundary((0,1))=cl[(0,1])$ \ $(0,1)=[0,1]$ \ $(0,1)=\{0,1\}$